# Implementing Serializable in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, object, serializable

I want to save my Android game state so the user can pick up and play from where he/she left off.
I have been reading about the serializable interface, but have some questions.

Aside from background rendering and a few other things my game is performed from one class.
Let me explain what that means. I have a class A, and all the different elements of the game are stored in various arraylists and such, in A. SO I have dozens of instances of classes B,C,D,E... all being called and updated (when the screen updates) from class A.

My problem is I am unsure what needs to be serializable. Every class B,C,D.. (i.e. every class? or just A? I don't see why serializing A and then saving the output in SQLite DB wouldnt store all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a suggestion, you may also want to look at [Berkeley DB Java Edition](http://bit.ly/gXs3rg), specifically at the [DPL (Data Persistence Layer) API](http://bit.ly/eLJzB8). Like SQLite, it's a transactionally protected, recoverable, fast, small footprint database library. However, the DPL allows you to directly persist your classes, making it a much easier choice for Java application developers.

Here's a [technical white paper](http://bit.ly/ek2a2U) describing the API and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to serialize some object. then look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953466/how-to-store-hashmap-so-that-it-can-be-retained-it-value-after-a-device-reboot/4954600#4954600) use other object in place of hashmmap object that has been specified in this link.