# dynamic spinner and sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, dynamic, spinner, auto-populate

in my android application I have a Button which adds a new dynamic Spinner to the Layout. All of the created Spinners are using the same Array.

What is working until now, I can save the number of created Spinners and recreate them after restarting the Application. 
But I really would like to save the selectedPosition of each Spinner in the sharedPreferences and this is where I'm stucking in a ForceClose Desaster...

In my understanding, every Spinner gets an ID when created so you can save the Position bounded on this ID in the preferences.

So this is what I did:

```
public void addSpinner(){

    LinearLayout AddLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearAddScroll);
    spinner = new Spinner(this);
    ArrayAdapter<?> adapt = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.Filter, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapt.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapt);
    AddLayout.addView(spinner);
    }
```

this creates the Spinner.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            addSpinner();


            int ID = 1000+x;
            spinner.setId(ID);
            Toast.makeText(MatReporterActivity.this,"ID" + ID, 5)
            .show();
            x++;
        }
```

set the ID.

This is what I do in the on Create method:

```
x = settings.getInt("xsave", 1);
    for(y = 1; y < x; y++){
        addSpinner();

        int ID = 1000+y;
        Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(ID);

        String ys= Integer.toString(ID);
        Toast.makeText(MatReporterActivity.this,"ID" +ys, 5)
        .show();
        int yf = settings.getInt(ys, 1);
        s.setSelection(yf);
        }
```

And this onStop():

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("xsave", x);
    for(y = 1; y < x; y++){
        int ID = 1000+y;
        Spinner s2= (Spinner) findViewById(ID);
        int possS = s2.getSelectedItemPosition();
        Toast.makeText(MatReporterActivity.this, "IDStop" + ID, 5)
        .show();
        String ys= Integer.toString(ID);
        editor.putInt(ys, possS);
    }

    editor.commit();
}
```

I think there is a logical Problem in the onCreate Method, but I'm not able to find it, also I didn't find any help in the web how to populate and save dynamically created spinners.

So maybe someone has an idea.
thanks.

Comment: Stack trace for your force close? Do you use LogCat (if not, you should).

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences are not a good way to store this kind of data. You should try to follow those 2 steps :

Create a class which implements Serializable to represent the data you want to store (you might use a list of Serializable objects)

```
public class SpinnerSave implements Serializable {
  public String ID;
  public int selection;

  public SpinnerSave(String ID, int selection){
    this.ID = ID;
    this.selection = selection;
  }
}
```

Then you should write your data into a file like so

```
private void saveState() {
final File cache_dir = this.getCacheDir(); 
final File suspend_f = new File(cache_dir.getAbsoluteFile() + File.separator + SUSPEND_FILE);

FileOutputStream   fos  = null;
ObjectOutputStream oos  = null;
boolean            keep = true;

try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(suspend_f);
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

    oos.writeObject(this.gameState);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    keep = false;
    Log.e("MyAppName", "failed to suspend", e);
}
finally {
    try {
        if (oos != null)   oos.close();
        if (fos != null)   fos.close();
        if (keep == false) suspend_f.delete();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { /* do nothing */ }
}
}
```

Comment: Ok I understand more or less your answer (I'm a bloody beginner :) ), but because I have a database already in my app, I would prefer to store it there. The thing is, I really don't know how to give the right position to a changing number of Spinners

Comment: Did you try to save a Hashmap with your spinner ID as key and its position as value?

Comment: Never heard of this before, but as far as I see it sounds interesting. Do this hashmaps survive the kill Process of the application or do I need to save them somehow.

Comment: You need to save it, you can look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953466/how-to-store-hashmap-so-that-it-can-be-retained-it-value-after-a-device-reboot) for a sample implementation