# Saving hash map into SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, hashmap, sharedpreferences

How can I save and get Hashmap in android using below format in SharedPreference

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> mChildMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Function to Insert HashMap into SharedPreference

```
private void insertToSP(HashMap<String, List<String>> jsonMap) {
  String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(jsonMap);
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("HashMap", MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
  editor.putString("map", jsonString);
  editor.apply();
}
```

Function to read hashMap from SharedPreference

```
private HashMap<String, List<String>> readFromSP(){
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("HashMap", MODE_PRIVATE);
   String defValue = new Gson().toJson(new HashMap<String, List<String>>());
   String json=sharedPreferences.getString("map",defValue);
   TypeToken<HashMap<String,List<String>>> token = new TypeToken<HashMap<String,List<String>>>() {};
   HashMap<String,List<String>> retrievedMap=new Gson().fromJson(json,token.getType());
   return retrievedMap;
}
```

Add this dependancy in gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use Google's Gson to save the HashMap as json.
Create a Wrapper class for your HashMap with the the getter and setter methods.
Refer the below answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11931812/5425930

Answer (score 1):

You can converti Hashmap as json with Gson library and put it as String. Something like this:

```
String converted = new Gson().toJson(myMap);
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("mySharedName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPreferences.edit().putString("key",converted).commit();
```