# java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.example.expandablelistview.NewsItem

Tags: java, android, hashmap, sharedpreferences, expandablelistview

I'm trying to save the expandablelistview child data to [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). The saving is working but when I try to load it then I get errors.

**Problem:**

When trying to load the settings and put it in a [HashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html) I get these errors (shorted to 3 lines):

```
08-24 12:40:05.138: E/AndroidRuntime(807): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-24 12:40:05.138: E/AndroidRuntime(807): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.example.expandablelistview.NewsItem
08-24 12:40:05.138: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at com.example.expandablelistview.ExpandableListAdapter.getChildView(ExpandableListAdapter.java:62)
```

For saving the data I'll use this code:

```
    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor= pref.edit();

    for( Entry<String, List<NewsItem>> entry : listDataChild.entrySet() )  {
          editor.putString( entry.getKey(), String.valueOf(entry.getValue())); // Save the values of listDataChild
    }

    editor.commit();
```

The output of the data is:

```
Yesterday: [[ headline=51.17346, 3.2252, Speed=2.10KM/H, Direction=158, date=18-8-2013 13:37:32]]
Older: [[ headline=51.74346, 3.23252, Speed=2.00KM/H, Direction=122, date=17-8-2013 11:40:30]]
Today: [[ headline=51.07346, 3.35252, Speed=0.00KM/H, Direction=122, date=19-8-2013 18:50:42]]
```

When trying to load these data (the errors happened here) and put it in a HashMap I'll use this ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151523/)):

```
    for( Entry<String, ?> entry : pref.getAll().entrySet() ) {
        listDataChild.put( entry.getKey(), (List<NewsItem>) Arrays.asList(entry.getValue()) ); // Put it in listDataChild
    }
```

The initialization of the data is happend here:

```
static void prepareListData(final Context context) {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<NewsItem>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("Today");
    listDataHeader.add("Yesterday");
    listDataHeader.add("Older");
    List<NewsItem> today = new ArrayList<NewsItem>();
    NewsItem newsData = new NewsItem();
    newsData.setHeadline("51.07346, 3.35252");
    newsData.setSpeed("0.00KM/H");
    newsData.setDirection("122");
    newsData.setDate("19-8-2013 18:50:42");
    today.add(newsData);

    List<NewsItem> yesterday = new ArrayList<NewsItem>();
    newsData = new NewsItem();
    newsData.setHeadline("51.17346, 3.2252");
    newsData.setSpeed("2.10KM/H");
    newsData.setDirection("158");
    newsData.setDate("18-8-2013 13:37:32");
    yesterday.add(newsData);

    List<NewsItem> older = new ArrayList<NewsItem>();
    newsData = new NewsItem();
    newsData.setHeadline("51.74346, 3.23252");
    newsData.setSpeed("2.00KM/H");
    newsData.setDirection("122");
    newsData.setDate("17-8-2013 11:40:30");
    older.add(newsData);

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), today);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), yesterday);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), older);
}
```

**Tried attempts:**

I've tried to change the `listdataChild.put` to load the data to this:

```
listDataChild.put( entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<NewsItem>((Collection<? extends NewsItem>) Arrays.asList(entry.getValue())) );
```

And to this:

```
listDataChild.put( entry.getKey(), (List<NewsItem>) new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(entry.getValue())) );
```

But without any results. (I've got the same error)

**Question:**

Is it possible to convert the map values to list and put it in the HashMap `listDataChild`?

Or should I use `newsData.setHeadline("Value");`, `newsData.setSpeed("Value");` etc.? (I don't know how to obtain specific values that's in `SharedPreferences` list)

<sup>(The source of `NewsItem.java` can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/FcYHba51), the source of `ExpandableListAdapter.java` can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/gGkZTkXX), and the source of `MainActivity.java` can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/tXVJkfrL))</sup>

Comment: I'm pretty sure the version of `ExpandableListAdapter` you've linked to *isn't* the one you're using, as the cast to `NewsItem` occurs on line 62, not 66 :(

Comment: @JonSkeet Woops, I have deleted a few lines before upload. It's now indeed on line 62. Thanks for you notice. :)

Comment: It doesn't help that you haven't shown where you're initializing the `ExpandableListAdapter`, either...

Comment: @JonSkeet [Here](http://pastebin.com/FLtxm03Y) is the full `MainActivity.java`. Do you also want the XML files?

Comment: No, although if you could put some work into reducing all the code to a *short* but complete example demonstrating the problem (and nothing else) it would make everyone's lives easier.

Comment: Why are your variables in MainActivity static? That sounds like a really bad idea to start with...

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm sorry for missing the short demonstration for the problem. The variables are static for later usage, it's possible to change `preparelistData` to a `private void`.

Comment: The variables being static really *really* feels like a mistake to me. It doesn't make sense for two instances of the class to share data, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the advice, I've changed it to 'normal' variables. See [here](http://pastebin.com/tXVJkfrL) for the change.

Comment: And a short but complete program which *only* demonstrates the problem? There should be no need to link to code elsewhere.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have slightly modified the post. I hope it's good.

Comment: Well it *still* isn't a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, is it? I'm still waiting for *minimal* code showing the problem - it shouldn't need to load the data from anywhere, or do anything complicated... just the bare minimum to demonstrate what's going wrong.

Comment: the problem seems to be the way you are saving data at        'String.valueOf(entry.getValue())' in 'editor.putString(...'

Comment: so the issue happened here ' (List<NewsItem>) Arrays.asList(entry.getValue()) );'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already pointed out your, expectations of simply using `Arrays.asList()` and casting to your data list is incorrect and will not work. As you use `SharedPreferences.Editor.putString()` you'll insert a `String` in the preferences representing the string returned by `List.toString()`(which will print all of its children(using `toString()`) in square brackets). When you get this string from the preferences back, you need to build it up into a `List` of `NewsItems`. One way of how you can do this would be like below:

```
for (Entry<String, ?> entry : pref.getAll().entrySet()) {
                    List<NewsItem> rowItems = new ArrayList<NewsItem>();
                    // the string from the preferences as it was saved
                    String prefContent = (String) entry.getValue();
                    // break against possible multiple NewsItems(I'm assuming that's 
                    // why you use a List of NewsItems) for the same
                    // key (every NewsItem starts with * so we split after
                    // that(see the NewsItems.toString method))
                    String[] newsItems = prefContent.split("\\*");
                    for (String item : newsItems) {
                        // an item which doesn't have at least 50 characters
                        // isn't a valid NewsItem string representation(based on
                        // its toString() method)
                        if (item.length() > 50) {
                            // ; is the delimiter for the NewsItem's data
                            String[] components = item.split(";");
                            NewsItem ni = new NewsItem();
                            // for each of the four data components we split
                            // after = and then use the second value obtained as
                            // that will be the value for that component
                            ni.setHeadline((components[0].split("="))[1]);
                            ni.setSpeed((components[1].split("="))[1]);
                            ni.setDirection((components[2].split("="))[1]);
                            ni.setDate((components[3].split("="))[1]);
                            rowItems.add(ni);
                        }
                    }
                    listDataChild.put(entry.getKey(), rowItems);
                }
```

The code above would require a change in the `toString()` method of the `NewsItem` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("*headline=");
    sb.append(headline);
    sb.append(";");
    sb.append("speed=");
    sb.append(speed);
    sb.append(";");
    sb.append("direction=");
    sb.append(direction);
    sb.append(";");
    sb.append("date=");
    sb.append(date);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Only one thing when I see the list after the `Date` string there is a `,` displayed and if it's the last item on the list its a `]`. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: @GerritHoekstra What happens if you add the line `sb.append(";");` in the `toString()` method like this: `...sb.append("date=");     sb.append(date);sb.append(";"); return sb.toString();`?

Comment: @GerritHoekstra The `sb.append(";");` should work. The extra `,` and `]` comes from the fact that a `List` will print its items between `[` and `]` separating the items with `,`. Because of this when doing the split after `;` the last component(the date) will get either a `,` or a `]` for the last element. But inserting a `;` after the date in the `toString()` method would make the split after `;` to move the extra `,` or `]` in another `components` index.

Comment: Thanks you're right, I saw the cached version of it. Do you also know how to add data to the list in another `private void` without overriding the previous data? Or should I use [Guava Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) for this case? I've tried to implement that with no luck.

Comment: @GerritHoekstra I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. If you plan to add other NewsItems(simple object or from another list of items) to a list belonging to a key then you can't use `HashMap.put(key, newData)` but you could use `List<NewsItems> list = HashMap.get(key);' and then add the new data to this list. If you plan to have a key pointing to more than one lists of NewsItems then it would probably be a good idea to use that multimap.

Comment: Thanks it's working! Only the item is now added to the bottom of the child `Today` is it possible to put the item to the top?

Comment: @GerritHoekstra I assume that you can use the index 0 when adding the new `NewsItem` to the `list list.add(0, object)`.

Comment: Do you also know how to add a item to `ExpandableListView` from another activity? I've asked the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622417/adding-a-item-from-another-activity-to-expandablelistview).

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the `String` you get back from `SharedPreferences` somehow to a list of `NewsItem`. A cast alone will not do that.

Answer (score 2):

this exceptions means that you are trying to assign a String object to a com.example.expandablelistview.NewsItem reference variable

i know this doesnt help much, but any way

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about -

> Is it possible to convert the map values to list and put it in the
>   HashMap listDataChild?

As you are looking for to save the POJO data in shared pref. You can use the **JSON** format to serialize your NewsItemList and the objects it contains, and then store is as a String into the SharedPreferences. [Google-JSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is a good api for this.

When you want to get the data back, retrieve the String and use a JSONArray to retrieve each object and add it to a new NewsItemList.

Otherwise, try **serializing** your object to a **private file**. This will help you to go beyond SharedPreferences's putString(), putFloat(), putLong(), putInt() and putBoolean().
Thank you.