# Adding a item from another activity to ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, android-activity, hashmap, expandablelistview

I want to add a item to the child `Today` from another activity to the `ExpandableListView`. The activity where I want to add it is named `LocHistory`, here is a the code to add something to the list:

```java
static void addListData(final Context context) {
    List<NewsItem> list = listDataChild.get("Today");
    NewsItem newsData = new NewsItem();
    newsData = new NewsItem();
    newsData.setHeadline("11.11111, 1.1111");
    newsData.setSpeed("1.11KM/H");
    newsData.setDirection("111");
    newsData.setDate("11-1-1111 11:11:11");
    list.add(0, newsData);
    listDataChild.put("Today", list);
}
```

This is working when I have call the function in the same class (`LocHistory`). But when I call it in `MainActivity` like this:

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LocHistory.addListData(getBaseContext());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then there is nothing added to the list. Is it possible to add a item from another activity to `ExpandableListView`? I want if there's something added that the class `LocHistory` is not going to open, so I think `startActivity` with a intent is not a option here (but i'm not sure).

<sup>(The java sources can be found here:
[MainActivity.java](http://pastebin.com/YWyfznwv),
[LocHistory.java](http://pastebin.com/XJ274C61),
[NewsItem.java](http://pastebin.com/uhmXbnhJ) and
[ExpandableListAdapter.java](http://pastebin.com/5jPV8daz))</sup>

**Edit:**

As some guys on a other forum pointed out, I'm now using `SharedPreferences`. I'm using this code:

```
static void addListData (int TimeStamp, final String lat, final String lng, final String speed,
        final String direction, final Context context){

    int todaystamp = startOf("today");
    int yesterdaystamp = startOf("yesterday");
    String Datetime = DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy kk:mm:ss", new Date(TimeStamp * 1000L)).toString();

    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

    if (TimeStamp >= todaystamp) {
        editor.putString("Today", "*headline=" + lat + ", " + lng +  ";speed=" + speed + ";direction=" +  direction + ";date=" + Datetime + ";");
    } else if (TimeStamp >= yesterdaystamp) {
        editor.putString("Yesterday", "*headline=" + lat + ", " + lng +  ";speed=" + speed + ";direction=" +  direction + ";date=" + Datetime + ";");
    } else if (TimeStamp < yesterdaystamp) {
        editor.putString("Older", "*headline=" + lat + ", " + lng +  ";speed=" + speed + ";direction=" +  direction + ";date=" + Datetime + ";");
    }

    editor.commit();
}
```

But now I'm stuck with one problem, when I add a item to the `SharedPreferences` on the same key it will overwrite the previous data. How can I add data to the same key without overwriting the previous data? Is it maybe possible to first get the data and then join the item to the data after that add the data to the `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: You don't see the new item in the `list` or `listDataChild`? Or in the adapter you don't see the new item?

Comment: @Luksprog I don't see it in the list under the child `Today` (so I think that is the adapter(?)). But it seems when I log the `listDataChild` in the function `addListData`  that it's added in the list under `Today` (the logging is only working when I first open the class `LocHistory` and close it).

Comment: I still don't get what you're trying to do and how did you test your current implementation. Calling that method from the `MainActivity` or the `LocHistory` class should work with no problems, with a successful NewsItem being added to the list under the `Today` key. If you print the map at the end of that method you should see the new item in it. keep in mind that you initialize the map and the list only when `LocHistory` activity is run.

Comment: @Luksprog The `prepareListData` function is called in the `onCreate` method. Is it maybe that function overrides the `listDataChild` that is created by the function `addListData`?

Comment: @Luksprog I've added a possible solution using `SharedPreferences`. But now I've one problem, when I add a item to the `SharedPreferences` on the same key it will overwrite the previous data. How can I add data to the same key without overwriting the previous data? Is it maybe possible to first get the data and then join the item to the data after that add the data to the `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: *Is it maybe possible to first get the data...* - of course it's possible. Before you do the `putString()` call retrieve the data for that key. Then do the data joining between this older and newer data sets(I don't know how you plan to do the data join) and then put the resulting data back in the preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you last edit you can try this:

```
static void addListData(int TimeStamp, final String lat, final String lng,
        final String speed, final String direction, final Context context) {

    int todaystamp = startOf("today");
    int yesterdaystamp = startOf("yesterday");
    String Datetime = DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy kk:mm:ss", new Date(TimeStamp * 1000L)).toString();

    String location = "*headline=" + lat + ", " + lng + ";speed=" + speed
            + ";direction=" + direction + ";date=" + Datetime + ";";

    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",
            MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

    if (TimeStamp >= todaystamp) {
        String today = pref.getString("Today",null);
        if (today != null) {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(today);
            str.insert(0, location + ", ");
            editor.putString("Today", str.toString());
        } else {
            editor.putString("Today", location);
        }
    } else if (TimeStamp >= yesterdaystamp) {
        String yesterday = pref.getString("Yesterday",null);
        if (yesterday != null) {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(yesterday);
            str.insert(0, location + ", ");
            editor.putString("Yesterday", str.toString());
        } else {
            editor.putString("Yesterday", location);
        }
    } else if (TimeStamp < yesterdaystamp) {
        String older = pref.getString("Older",null);
        if (older != null) {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(older);
            str.insert(0, location + ", ");
            editor.putString("Older", str.toString());
        } else {
            editor.putString("Older", location);
        }
    }

    editor.commit();
}
```

This will ensure that it not overrides the key but append if it exists. (This is done by checking whether the `SharedPreferences` is not null for a specific key).

I use [`StringBuilder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) with the [`insert`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) method in this case.