# How to store HashMap on Android?

Tags: android, hashmap, storage

So, I'm trying to store `HashMap` on Android. I think it's better to use [internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal), but I don't understand *how to save* `HashMap` in it *and then read it later*. Can someone explain how to do that properly, please?

There are counters with their own names and values. I want to load them onсe when some activity was started, work with them (change, delete, add new), and then save that data to use next time. Right now I use HashMap because it's easy to delete/add values.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> counters;
```

Comment: where you want to store in some file as persistance? or until your Application is running.

Comment: please explain your exact requirement for storage.

Comment: more description please.

Comment: Sure, added more information.

Comment: you can serialize in json and save it in sharedpref as a string

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SharedPreferences also store data in key-value pair as hashmap, so why not get all key-values from hashmap and store into map, as it:

```
SharedPreferences pref= getContext().getSharedPreferences("Your_Shared_Prefs"), 
                                                           Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor= pref.edit();

    for (String s : map.keySet()) {
        editor.putString(s, map.get(s));
    }
```

To fetch values you can use:

```
public abstract Map<String, ?> getAll ()
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getAll%28%29

use:

```
SharedPreferences pref= getContext().getSharedPreferences("Your_Shared_Prefs"), 
                                                           Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
HashMap<String, String> map= HashMap<String, String> pref.getAll();
for (String s : map.keySet()) {
        String value=map.get(s);
        //Use Value
    }
```

Code is not compiled, so it may have some minor errors, but should work.

Comment: Can you show an example of fetching values using that method, please?

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
hashMap.put("key", "value");
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyOtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("map", hashMap);
startActivity(intent);
```

and Another way is [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953466/how-to-store-hashmap-so-that-it-can-be-retained-it-value-after-a-device-reboot)

Answer (score 1):

There's a good example [here](https://freakycoder.com/android-notes-41-how-to-save-and-get-hashmap-into-sharedpreference-e686ead94b6c).

So if your Map is like so:

```
HashMap<String, byte[]> = new HashMap<>();
```

The functions look like this:

```
public void saveHashMap(String key , Object obj) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(obj);
    editor.putString(key,json);
    editor.apply();     // This line is IMPORTANT !!!
}

public HashMap<String,byte[]> getHashMap(String key) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = prefs.getString(key,"");
    java.lang.reflect.Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String,byte[]>>(){}.getType();
    HashMap<String,byte[]> obj = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    return obj;
}
```

The Generic code looks like this:

```
public void saveHashMap(String key , Object obj) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(obj);
    editor.putString(key,json);
    editor.apply();     // This line is IMPORTANT !!!
}


public HashMap<Integer,YourObject> getHashMap(String key) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = prefs.getString(key,"");
    java.lang.reflect.Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<Integer,YourObject>>(){}.getType();
    HashMap<Integer,YourObject> obj = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    return obj;
}
```

Replace `YourObject` with, well, your Java object.