# Is it possible to store a HashMap with the value as an ArrayList in SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, hashmap, sharedpreferences, persistence

I have a `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<MyTeam>>` where the class `MyTeam` is a POJO. There will be at most 5 items in each `ArrayList` object. Is it possible to save this kind of `HashMap` to `SharedPreferences`? If not, what is another alternative? I need this data to be saved when the app is closed and reloaded when it starts up.

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227016/how-to-store-hashmap-on-android) answer but the Key and Value attributes are both String and my case is a bit more complicated than just String data types. Will this method still work? Is there a better way?

Comment: convert it into JSON object and then save it to sharedpreferences

Comment: You can try with **Set**, checkout [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7057858/4790490)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to save this kind of HashMap to SharedPreferences?

Not directly. You are welcome to convert that into JSON and save it as a string preference. Then, to load it back in, you would read in the string and use a JSON parser to reconstitute your objects.

[This class](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Documents/TinyTextEditor/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/tte/EditHistory.java) demonstrates the basic technique, though it is saving a `List<Uri>`, not a `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<MyTeam>>`. I specifically used this sample to demonstrate the use of the built-in `JSONReader` and `JSONWriter` classes; for a real app, I would consider Gson or a similar [JSON parsing library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/50).

> If not, what is another alternative?

Save it to a SQLite database, probably through a couple of tables. Or, save it to some sort of file, in a file format of your choosing (e.g., JSON, XML).