# Best practice to handle a variable (yet small) amount of saved items

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sqlite

I need to provide my users the ability to add buttons to a screen. These buttons will have a standard action (send an sms with a predefined text). How should i save those items? They will have a name and a text, could be deleted and MAYBE dragged to change position.
Should I use sqlite and a listview with a loader or just sharedpreferences (but i don't know how in this case) with the buttons added programmatically to the layout.
The number of items will be really small (in most cases <10) so the work for sqlite seems a bit too much (and i wouldn't like to use the listview).

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful?

Comment: No, i went for the database way! Thank you anyway!

Comment: Would be nice id you told me or at least vote  for the answer... I like to help people but I don't don't like to spend my time for nothing...

Answer (score 0):

This answer seems to be the best for you!
(from what I understood from your question)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4955428/327402

It show how you can store a pair String-String in preferences.

The alternative would be to save it in the memory:

```
File file = new File(getDir("data", MODE_PRIVATE), "map");    
ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
outputStream.writeObject(map);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```